# How do i make a bot send a message in a specific channel with on_message

Tags: python, discord.py

I didnt really wanna ask this but ive been having trouble, I keep getting errors when i want to try and send a message in a specifc channel, heres the code thats important:

```
channel = client.get_channel(CHANNELID)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id != BOTID:
        await channel.send(f"**{message.author.name}** - {datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} {datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S')} - {message.content}")
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

The error i get is

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Another side question, it is possible to make it send it in a different server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to hard-code guild and channel IDs. Like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id != BOTID:
        guild = client.get_guild(guildID)
        channel = guild.get_channel(channelID)
        await channel.send(f"**{message.author.name}** - {datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} {datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S')} - {message.content}")
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Instead of `guildID` and `channelID` put IDs of your choice. If you don't know how to get IDs:

1. Go to user settings
2. Go to advanced tab
3. Turn on developer mode
4. Right click on anything that you want an ID of
5. Click `Copy ID`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you defined `channel = client.get_channel(CHANNELID)`, your guild cache wasn't filled and therefore the get_channel returned None. One option is to go as loloToster said and get the guild and channel every time. I find it easier to just set it on_ready:

```py
channel = client.get_channel(CHANNELID)  # Will be None originally (I won't write None as if you work with some linters, they will send warnings about 'send' not found in NoneType). Also, get_guild().get_channel() is more efficient as it involves less iteration (although this will only affect u if u have a large number of servers on your bot)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global channel
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNELID)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user and channel is not None:
        await channel.send(f"**{message.author.name}** - {datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')} - {message.content}")
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

For your side question of can you send it to a different server, yes of course, just provide the channel id of a channel in another server as your argument to get_channel

Answer (score 0):

While other answers are all valid and pretty insightful, there is an easier fix here.
You can send a message to a specific channel using the `fetch_channel(CHANNELID)`. It is an API call and thus there is no issue of cache or anything else.

```py
channel = await client.fetch_channel(CHANNELID)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id != BOTID:
        await channel.send(f"**{message.author.name}** - {datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} {datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S')} - {message.content}")
        await client.process_commands(message)
```